# Too much space between full paragraph and subequations env

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I have a document using subequations and the parskip package. If the paragraph before a subequations environment is completely filled up to the last line, then additional vertical whitespace is introduced between this paragraph and the following subequations. I guess this is a bug, but I'm not sure, nor do I have enough TeX knowledge to try and fix it. How can I fix this whitespace issue?

Below is a MWE which shows the behaviour, at least on LaTeX2e <2003/12/01> with pdfeTeX 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (unfortunately on this machine only an old tetex distribution is installed).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The subequations environment provides a convenient way to number a foos
\begin{subequations}\label{foo}
  \begin{align}
    x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
    a &= b + c
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `parskip` does not seem to have anything to do with it. Remove it and insert a `\noindent` before the first line and you will get the same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the space after `foos` does not disappear at the line break, because of the `\begin{subequations}` that follows (I don't know exactly why).

Use `\begin{subequations}` between paragraphs, or say

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\subequations{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}
```

In daleif's example the problem is the same: a space remains and makes a new line in the paragraph. However a `\label` there is only for `\pageref` usage, so it *must* be attached to a word, otherwise the reference can be off by one.

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same issue. But this solution is not working for me. any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: @cosmicraga Difficult to say without a minimal example; please, make a new question citing this one and showing a bit of code that presents the issue.

Comment: After removing all other packages and codes, it works fine. So It must be clash between packages in my case. my document is quite big and I do not have time at present to see which package or chunk of code is causing the error. So sorry for not posting the MWE. Thanks.

Comment: One can also do `\AtBeginEnvironment{subequations}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}`; similarly, `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}` and `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}` cure the problem for those two environments.

Answer (score 2):

No idea what on earth is going on here. But here is a simpler example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent The subequations environment provides a convenient way to
number a foos%
\label{foo}
\begin{align}
  x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
  a &= b + c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

remove the `%` and we are back at your problem.

Comment: On closer inspection, the problem even occurs without the `\noindent` as long as the text fills the line. But you were right that it wasn't specific to the parskip package.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which shows that the `\mbox` is in a new line and we get the same vertical space as with no space before the `\mbox`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\noindent The subequations environment provides a convenient way to
number a foos
\mbox{}\rlap{\rule{1pt}{2ex}\rule{0.6\linewidth}{1pt}}
\begin{align}
  x^2 + y^2 &= z^2\\
  a &= b + c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]