# fleqn document class option, long text lines, and hyperref package

Tags: spacing, hyperref, equations

When the `fleqn` option is used, the vertical spacing before an equation placed right after a "long" text line (exactly `\linewidth` I would say) is improperly set up. See below:

[image]

From the `mathmode` user guide, this could probably be fixed through the `\topsep` length.
Is it the right way to proceed? The problem is reproduced by the code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{plo}
\section{plo}
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaem oeiu eoiu eoiu oeee.
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaemm
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaem oeiu eoiu eoiu oeee.
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùae
\begin{equation}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

There is something wrong involving `hyperref`, `amsmath`, and `fleqn`. Removing one of those removes the problem.

Comment: Please show an example document that produces the image. Are you using amsmath or default latex setting?

Comment: Is there some relation with the fact that the line ends with `:`?

Comment: Note that you should never leave empty lines around/between display equations and surrounding text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just edited the message.

Comment: @Sigur No relation.

Comment: I see the same space in both cases ....\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 12.0 plus 3.0 minus 7.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 3.71825  (TeXLive 2013)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am also using Texlive 2013 (on windows). Where do you read these `\glue` lines?

Comment: @pluton  add `\showoutput`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But there's an empty line before the first display: `\glue(\baselineskip) 12.16669`.

Comment: @egreg correct: that is what I see as well.

Comment: @egreg not here, I'll post an image

Comment: This is reproducable under TeX Live 2011 (on [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last line before the first equation ends with a space. This is usually not a problem,
because TeX ends the text before the displayed equation similar to a paragraph end. That means, the last space is removed and `\parfillskip` is added.

However, package `hyperref` has to insert whatsits somewhere at some time. It hooks into `\refstepcounter`, that is called right before displaying the equation to update the
equation counter. `hyperref` uses this to add an anchor that is needed as link target,
if the equation if referenced.

However, then the last space of the previous text cannot be removed, because the whatsit/anchor goes inbetween, hiding the space. Because the text fills the previous line, the result is a line break, followed by an invisible line with the anchor. The space is removed at the start of the new line, but the invisible line remains, consuming space.

As quick workaround, the space can be removed by a percent line:

```
...aemm%
\begin{equation}
```

Better is a fix that does remove the space automatically and fixes the position of the anchor, because the position at the end of the previous line is not a good place.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\equation}{\incr@eqnum\mathdisplay@push}{%
  \ifhmode
    \unskip
    \vadjust{%
      \incr@eqnum
      \global\let\gfix@incr@eqnum\incr@eqnum
      \global\let\gfix@currentlabel\@currentlabel
      \global\let\gfix@currentHref\@currentHref
    }%
    \let\incr@eqnum\gfix@incr@eqnum
    \let\@currentlabel\gfix@currentlabel
    \let\@currentHref\gfix@currentHref
  \else
    \incr@eqnum
  \fi
  \mathdisplay@push
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{plo}
\section{plo}
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaem oeiu eoiu
eoiu oeee.
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaemm
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùaeoiuaem oeiu eoiu
eoiu oeee.
eoiu oieu oeiuoe ueoi ueoi ueoiu eoiu oeu oe iupaêio umùae
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
\cos\pi=-1
\end{equation}
Equations \ref{eq:first} and \ref{eq:second}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest adding an \ifhmode\unskip to equation as a workaround to save patching hyperref internals, but this is much better:-)

Comment: Will this patch be included in a coming version of `hyperref`?

Comment: @pluton: It is on my ToDo list for `hyperref`. But other projects (e.g. release of my bundle) have currently more priority.

Comment: perfectly fine. No pressure :)

Comment: just out of curiosity: I had somehow the same problem (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284939/44467) and just found this old question. Is this patch already included in `hyperref`?

Comment: @Faekynn Probably not yet.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek in case you patch it somewhen: I think also appears with any other equation environment like `multline`, `align`, `alignat` etc.
 For `alignat`, it worked just to replace `\equation` with `\alignat` in your code, but for `alignat` with surrounding `subequations` it did not work.

Comment: for `subequation`, I took the solution from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27058/44467