# Extra spacing before an equation when line nearly breaks

Tags: spacing, equations, line-breaking

I am having difficulty with producing an MWE, but let me describe the issue. I have a large document with tons of equations and run into issues with spacing. Most of the time it is fine, everything looks good; however, precisely when the line immediately prior to the equation is about to break (i.e., the text fills the entire line), the equation is preceded with additional vertical spacing, as seen on the image below.

[image: Error]

Equation (5.15) shows this issue, however (5.16) does not. Since the line before (5.15) is about to break, is there a chance that the extra space is due to an empty line being inserted?

I tried reproducing this exact situation to produce an MWE, but `XeLaTeX` makes different line-breaking decisions. As a result I cannot reproduce this precise error. Any clues about the causes of this behavior or ways to avoid it?

This is the offending fragment:

```
particles separately, effectively using $M = 1$, but consider executing the sampling algorithm in an unchanged form, but simultaneously for $M \geq 1$ at a time. At the coarsest level we generate $M$ samples
\begin{equation}
 \vec x_{V_m}^j \sim \hat{P}(\vec x_{V_m}^j)
\end{equation}
and perform the conditional
```

Comment: Since the equation (math) forms part of the discussion, it should also form part of the sentence, and therefore you should not leave a blank (empty) line before you start the display math environment.

Comment: there's a (rather unlikely) situation that could result in this extra space even if there's no blank line involved.  if for some reason the line before (5.15) ends in a "forced" space (say the input is `samples {}` ), and there's no room for that space on that line, an extra blank line will be forced.  there will be an "underfull \hbox (badness 10000)" in the log file to point this out.  a more frequent cause of such a blank line (and not just between text and a display) is the insertion of a double backslash  \\ at the end of the line; this too will get an "underfull" message.

Comment: To clear up the matter, there is no line break or any weird symbols at the end, text flows as you see it. @barbarabeeton: I will double-check the log.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I have checked the log and could not find anything of the sort.

Comment: more information needed.  at a minimum, document class and options (it looks like `[fleqn]` is involved, judging from the inserted output example).

Comment: This is a version of `ClassicThesis` compiled under `XeLaTeX`, with `amsmath[fleqn]`, `unicode-math` and a host of other things. I tried reproducing this behavior, but failed with this minimal set of packages.

Comment: so what happens if you put a `%` after `samples` to comment out the line end before the equation?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had the same problem, and the `%` at the line end before the equations helped! Is this the only solution, or do I have to insert `%`s everywhere?

Comment: @Faekynn an example is needed, as putting a `%` there should make no difference, so something is wrong  with the setup

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made a new question with an MWE, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284939/too-much-spacing-between-equations-and-text

Comment: This question is actually a duplicate of [too much spacing between equations and text if line before equation is full](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284939/5764), which in turn is a duplicate of [`fleqn` document class option, long text lines, and `hyperref` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122343/5764).