# too much spacing between equations and text if line before equation is full

Tags: spacing, hyperref, amsmath, scrbook

I have a problem when equations appear in the text without a linebreak. It seems like an additional spacing before an equation is inserted, when the line before the equation is just full until the end...

The problem only appears with documentclass `scrbook` (at least not with `article`) and with the packages `amsmath` with the option `fleqn` and `hyperref`! Removing one of these options/packages/... also removes the additional spacing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}   
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\begin{equation}
test
\end{equation}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\begin{equation}
test
\end{equation}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test%
\begin{equation}
test
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The parskip option is only for the first line not to be intended. As one can see before the second equation (0.2), there's an additional vertical spacing inserted compared to the spacing of equation (0.1).

The effect does not appear, if an `%` comments out the newline character, or if the `\begin{equation}` is written directly in the text line, without a newline in the .tex-file, which can be seen before equation (0.3).
[image: compiled MWE]

A similar problem was already mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150725/extra-spacing-before-an-equation-when-line-nearly-breaks), but without solution.

Edit:

A solution (for the package `hyperref`) is given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122358/44467.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27053/too-much-space-between-full-paragraph-and-subequations-env. There a workaround is offered to remove the extra space between a full line and an equation environment using the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: @eldering Yes, the workaround seems to be working (with `equation` instead of `subequations`).

Comment: @eldering -- i've asked egreg in the chat to expand his answer so it covers both situations.

Comment: @barbarabeeton maybe it could be possible to make it even more general, for any math environment without naming them explicitly? (also `align`, `multline` etc.) That would be great!

Comment: @Faekynn -- yes, i did request that.