# Is subequations known to introduce vertical white space?

Tags: spacing, subequations

In this MWE, there is additional white space between the line of text and the following `subequations` environment. It disappears when I unload `hyperref`, when I remove the wrapping `subequations` environment, when I shorten the line of text, or when I append `%` to the line of text.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\begin{document}
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi 
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{equation}
            X
        \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

But why does it appear in the first place, and can this be fixed?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122343/fleqn-document-class-option-long-text-lines-and-hyperref-package

Comment: @pluton Thanks again, this led me to an alternative answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place `\begin{subequations}` before starting the paragraph, which is the position it should go to begin with.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}
\begin{document}

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
X
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
\begin{equation}
X
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
\begin{equation}
X
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a good fix. Do you happen to have some documentation that explains that this is "the position it should go to begin with"? Because in the only official example that I can find, it is not in that position: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/subeqn.tex

Comment: @bers Well, it ought to work even in that position, but `hyperref` adds some hooks that make the break between the “paragraph-so-far” and the equation into something different as usual. It's my opinion that `subequation` should encompass full paragraphs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @pluton's comment, referring me to [fleqn document class option, long text lines, and hyperref package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122343/fleqn-document-class-option-long-text-lines-and-hyperref-package), I found @Faekynn's comment referring me futher to [Too much space between full paragraph and subequations env](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27053/too-much-space-between-full-paragraph-and-subequations-env) and the accepted answer there. So this one also solves my problem without messing with the order of environments:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,hyperref}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\subequations{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}

\begin{document}
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi 
    mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmi
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{equation}
        X
        \end{equation}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```