# How to remove vertical space when subequations are used along with empheq?

Tags: spacing, subequations, empheq

I am using empheq along with subequations as given in the MWE. However, the use of subequations create a vertical space between the paragraph and equation as shown in figure, which I don't want. I already tried answers available in [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27053/too-much-space-between-full-paragraph-and-subequations-env),[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352556/is-subequations-known-to-introduce-vertical-white-space). Both the answers are not available to remove the space. Implementation of these answers provided in MWE 1 and 2, respectively.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left={H=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
        & 2 G_{0} - 2.6 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~<~100~K \\
        & 2 G_{0} - 9.8 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~>~100~K  
    \end{empheq}
    \label{eq:k_temperature_correlation}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**MWE 1**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\subequations{\ifhmode\unskip\fi}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left={H=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
        & 2 G_{0} - 2.6 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~<~100~K \\
        & 2 G_{0} - 9.8 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~>~100~K  
    \end{empheq}
    \label{eq:k_temperature_correlation}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**MWE 2**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\lipsum
    \begin{empheq}[left={H=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
        & 2 G_{0} - 2.6 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~<~100~K \\
        & 2 G_{0} - 9.8 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~>~100~K  
    \end{empheq}
    \label{eq:k_temperature_correlation}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

***How to remove vertical space between equation and paragraph when using combination of subequations and empheq?***

Comment: I've tried to remove both `subequations` and `empheq` (replaced it by the `align` environment). The vertical space remains. It disappears after I drop the `empheq` package or remove the `overload` option. Though it disappears for `align` only. For `empheq` it strikes again. So I think the issue is in the `empheq` package and not in `subequations`.

Comment: I see no particular excess space in MWE2, provided the ending `\par` of `\lipsum` is suppressed (`\lipsum*`). There's no rule about having to do like in MWE1. I'd say that to the contrary it is better to include in `subequations` also the paragraph parts before and after the equations/displays involved in `subequations`.

Answer (score 3):

The additional space is an artifact of using `lipsum`, which by default adds a `\par` at the end of each `\lipsum` command.

Without `lipsum` you can see that the space is OK:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\sta}{some random text}
\newcommand{\stb}{\sta\space\sta\space\sta\space\sta\space\sta}
\newcommand{\st}{\stb\space\stb\space\stb}

\begin{document}
\st
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left={H=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
        & 2 G_{0} - 2.6 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~<~100~K \\
        & 2 G_{0} - 9.8 \quad \forall \quad G_{0}~>~100~K  
    \end{empheq}
    \label{eq:k_temperature_correlation}
\end{subequations}
\st

\bigskip

\begin{subequations}\label{a-better-place-for-label}
\st
    \begin{empheq}[left={H=\empheqlbrace\,}]{align}
        & 2 G_{0} - 2.6 \quad \forall\, G_{0} < \qty{100}{\kelvin} \\
        & 2 G_{0} - 9.8 \quad \forall\, G_{0} > \qty{100}{\kelvin}  
    \end{empheq}
\st
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Here I define `\st` so that it produces “some random text” several times.

[image]

Some points to note, for which you should look at the second part of the code above:

1. your `\label` is in the wrong place and you can clearly see the small indent after the display which is due exactly to the misplaced `\label`
2. since a display has related text above and usually also below, it's more consistent to have this text *inside* `subequations`
3. you're manually adding spaces around `>` and `<`: don't
4. symbols for units should be upright, so 100 K and not 100 *K*; exploit `siunitx` or type in `100\,\mathrm{K}` if your usage is occasional
5. the “for all” symbol should be removed or, at least, positioned nearer *G*<sub>0</sub>